# how to set a field's defaultValue to return value from another field in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following Model definition created for sequelize.js:

```
const Item = sequelize.define('item', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        lender: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue() {
                return this.getDataValue('owner');
            }
        },
        owner: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        tableName: 'items',
        underscored: true,
        updatedAt: false,
        createdAt: 'timestamp'
    }

);
```

My intent is that if the lender `lender` field is not provided, then it is set to the `owner` field.

When I run my unit test, I get the result, `TypeError: this.getDataValue() is not a function`.

[The documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes) shows an example of `defaultValue` being a function. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using sequelize 4.37 and PostgreSQL

Comment: `this` is not the current object which you are creating. Hence the error

Comment: @AbhinavD I've gathered that much from the error. So how do I get a value of another field and make it the default value of this one?

Comment: Sorry about that. AFAIK, sequelize does not support this. Of course you can add this check during the creation of the object at the application layer.

Answer (score 4):

You can set defaultValue to each key but this only used to create/fetch value of that specific column.
However if you want to get value of another column in case the desired column's value is null then you can use [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html).

You can apply [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html) on find, and whenever the value of your column is null, it will populate its value with the alternate column value.